# Confusion regarding Traits Inheritence

Tags: scala

I have written this code in Scala

```
class MI {
    def identity : Int = {
        println("came inside MI") 
        1
    }
}

trait DMI extends MI {
    override def identity : Int = {
        println("came inside DMI")
        2 * super.identity
    }
}

trait TMI extends MI {
    override def identity : Int = {
        println("came inside TMI")
        3 * super.identity
    }
}

class Foo extends TMI with DMI {
    override def identity : Int = super[DMI].identity
}

val f = new Foo
f.identity
```

The output of the code is

```
came inside DMI
came inside TMI
came inside MI
res5: Int = 6
```

Can anyone explain why did the call go inside of TMI? According to me the answer should have been 2.

Comment: Read this: http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/stackable_trait_pattern.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you are using *stackable behavior*. When Scala encounters `new`, it linearizes the class. This *linearization* decides which method in the chain will be called when `super` is encountered. For your example, linearization of `Foo` would be like:

```
Foo -> DMI -> TMI -> MI -> AnyRef -> Any
```

So if `super` is encountered in any of the method, the implementation will be picked from right to left. In this case, since `super[DMI].identity` is used in `identity` method of `Foo`:

- First it executes `identity` from `DMI` (since you have explicitly used `super[DMI]`
  linearization will not be used), which again has `super.identity` and
  as per linearization
- it executes `identity` from `TMI`, which again has `super.identity`
  and as per linearization
- it executes `identity` from `MI`

That's why you get `6` as final output.

*Note* that if you have called `super[TMI].identity` from inside `Foo`, result would have been `3`.

You can refer [this](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.6) link for more details about linearization.

Answer (score 1):

Structure of FOO is as below:

1. TMI with DMI  {Foo}
2. Expand all types until you reach Any

(Any with AnyRef with MI with TMI) with (Any with AnyRef with MI with DMI) with {Foo}

3. Move from left to right, remove all duplicates

(Any with AnyRef with MI with TMI) with (    DMI) with {Foo}

4. Below  is the resulting types .Now start from Right hand side and check how 'super'behaves

Any with AnyRef with MI with TMI with DMI with {Foo}